# Passive voice vs predicate adjective

Tags: passive

Is there a difference in meaning between

> Das Haus wurde zerstört

and

> Das Haus war zerstört

I can't make the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of the power of the German language: A small grammatical change in the sentence yields a complex change in meaning.

> 1. Das Haus *wurde zerstört*.
> 2. Das Haus *war zerstört*.

Both translate succinctly to

> The house *was destroyed*.

However, 1. describes a process (Vorgangspassiv) and 2. describes a condition (Zustandspassiv). The English translation needs more words to convey one or the other meaning:

> 1. The house *was destroyed* (by someone).
> 2. The house *was* (in a) *destroyed* (condition).

Now, I hope you see that, in fact, the two German sentences are fundamentally different.

Comment: In english, this distinction can also be expressed by _The house was destroyed._ vs. _The house got destroyed._, I guess.